# what is the meaning of the output of the users list command

Tags: adb, command-line

I'm using the `cmd user list` command and this is the output I'm getting from the shell.

> UserInfo{0:Owner:13}
>
> UserInfo{23:shalevM:20}

what does the last variable means? the first one is clearly the user's id and the second is the user's name, but the last one is changing from time to time and I don't know what does it mean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The structure of the output is as follows:

> UserInfo{**id**:**name**:**flags**}

Flags are basically bits of information describing the data model's level of access and/or permissions.

You can read some of the code comments on the flags defined in the `UserInfo` class here:

https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/java/android/content/pm/UserInfo.java

Comment: Why would it be changing... could that be a sign of changing permissions on the account ?

Comment: They most likely change as the user accepts/rejects permissions or other functional app settings because the value itself is a [bitmask](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mask_(computing)) representing multiple data points in one integer value.